# Can't connect with UDL file to SQL Server 2016 but with SSMS it works without problems

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

I have a strange issue using a UDL file.
I can't connect with the UDL file to SQL Server 2016 with a specific user (login) but when I'm trying to connect with the same user via SSMS,  it works without problems.

A Diffrent user can connect both ways without issues.

What's wrong with my user/UDL file?

Comment: I think you are going to need to show us the content of the UDL file - open it in notepad, change the server name/database name/user name/password to protect your security, but don't change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I found what caused it - UDL connections doesn't allow using a different Windows NT authentication other than the current user.
The "Custom user" is only for SQL authentication.

Comment: This is the case for all Windows authenticated connections, not just UDLs. Windows authentication uses the identity of the current process (e.g. logged in user).

Comment: @DanGuzman
yeah but you can run them as a different user. that's how I manage to connect with this user using ssms.

Comment: Right, Run As changes the process identity.